# How to scp something with public key in azure-pipelines?

Tags: docker, security, ssh, azure-pipelines, ssh-keys

My azure pipeline contains compiling of a project and building docker image from it.

Now I want to copy this image to target machine and run it there.

With shell script what I was doing is:

```
sudo docker build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm -t $docker_name .
sudo docker save $docker_name > $tar_name

scp $tar_name $target_path
```

I think I did `build` and `save` parts in azure-pipelines already.

But how to do scp? I need some ssh key in pipeline to authorize it on target machine. It's can't be my key pair since it will be compromised. How to make one for pipeline then?

---

Here is [the task description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops). It states, that

> The task supports use of an SSH key pair to connect to the remote
> machine(s).

But doesn't explain, how to use key pair if I have it.

Comment: If your question is how to create another SSH key for authentication, then it's not a programming question. Please move it to [su]. Though you create the new key the same was as the key you already have.

Comment: Suppose I have a key pair

Comment: I do not understand. You wrote that you do not want to use the key you have because *"it will be compromised"*.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it's like IDE question: too specific for `Super User`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `Azure` has special pipeline task called `CopyFilesOverSSH`. It receives key in the form of pre-configured "Service connection", which should be configured on seprate page:

[image]

Configuring `service connection` involves storing keys correctly.

There is no need to call `scp` command itself.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT sure, it was just not possible to do immediately

Answer (score 0):

The small issue with this task is, that it's not really SCP transfer - it's SFTP.
In my particular case it caused some confusion since I was given user with limited shell access and SFTP was not working :)